# AWS Amplify Push Notifications with React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

There seem to be some discrepancies in the documentation as to how to implement Push Notifications. Here is the RN code from the [AWS Amplify docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/push_notifications_setup.html):

```
import { PushNotificationIOS } from 'react-native';
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';
import PushNotification from '@aws-amplify/pushnotification';
import aws_exports from './aws_exports';

// PushNotification need to work with Analytics
Analytics.configure(aws_exports);

PushNotification.configure(aws_exports);
```

But we also need to configure Analytics as part of this, and here is that implementation from the [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/analytics_guide):

```
import Amplify, { Analytics } from 'aws-amplify';
import aws_exports from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
```

Note that in the Analytics implementation, there is only a single Amplify `configure`. But in the Push Notification docs we directly `configure` `Analytics` and `PushNotifications` but not `Amplify`. Which is it?

To add further confusion, I found [this Medium post](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-push-notifications-with-amazon-pinpoint-ios-b2efa89ced32) from an AWS developer advocate explaining the RN implementation a third way:

```
import { PushNotificationIOS } from 'react-native';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { PushNotification } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import aws_exports from './aws_exports';

Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
PushNotification.configure(aws_exports);
```

`PushNotification` is imported from `aws-amplify-react-native` instead of `aws-amplify`.

Totally confused here, and welcome any clarification!

Edit: Adding that I've tried various combinations of all these with no luck. `PushNotification` seems to be undefined and unable to configure.

Comment: Have you tried using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) instead?

Answer (score 3):

// UPDATE

Updated the first code snippet, because I registered 2 endpoints for one device with it.

// OLD ANSWER

The following step should work, first:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify;
import PushNotification from '@aws-amplify/pushnotification';
import awsExports from '../../../../../aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsExports);
// PushNotification.configure(awsExports); // registering 2 Endpoints for one device if running this line as well
```

Then, remember to run

```
npm install aws-amplify --save && npm install @aws-amplify/pushnotification --save
```

Especially the second part with the @ is important.

Lastly, in componentDidMount:

```
PushNotification.onNotification((notification) => {
  console.log('in app notification', notification);
  notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
});

PushNotification.onRegister((token) => {
  console.log('in app registration', token);
});
```

This is final solution for me, battled with it for 3 days.